# Can't Load statnet in R on Windows 10

Tags: r, statnet

I have run

```
install.packages('statnet')
library('statnet')
```

Result:

> Loading required package: tergm
>
> Loading required package: ergm
>
> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘ergm’ in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]):
>    there is no package called ‘statnet.common’
>
> Error: package ‘ergm’ could not be loaded
>
> In addition: Warning messages:
>   1: package ‘statnet’ was built under R version 3.4.4 
>   2: package ‘tergm’ was built under R version 3.4.4
>
> **Error: package ‘ergm’ could not be loaded** 
>   5.
>   stop(gettextf("package %s could not be loaded", sQuote(pkg)), 
>       call. = FALSE, domain = NA) 
>   4.
>   .getRequiredPackages2(pkgInfo, quietly = quietly) 
>   3.
>   library(pkg, character.only = TRUE, logical.return = TRUE, lib.loc = lib.loc, 
>       quietly = quietly) 
>   2.
>   .getRequiredPackages2(pkgInfo, quietly = quietly) 
>   1.
>   library(statnet)

Next I tried

```
install.packages('ergm') # Worked with warning: dependency ‘statnet.common’ is not available
```

But `library(statnet)` still does not work, and `library(ergm)` has a similar error message.

Also tried `install.packages(statnet.common)` but also get

> package ‘statnet.common’ is not available

I'm running RStudio Version 1.1.419, with **R version 3.4.3 on Windows 10**

Any ideas how to load `statnet` in R?

Answer (score 1):

Updating my version of R to 3.5.3 solved my problem.